# How to pronounce this notation

Tags: notation, pronunciation

Reading this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04644.pdf
the following term :
$$L_\infty$$
is referenced in the context of :

[image]

How is $L_\infty$ pronounced ? Is it just "L infinity" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ell infinity" or "Ell sub infinity"; both are fine. In this context, it reads most naturally to me as "Ell zero, ell two, and ell infinity".